# Create an installer for a Rails JRuby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tomcat, jruby, warbler

I have a Ruby On Rails 3 app that is installed under a Tomcat in Windows XP. I used jruby and warbler to create the war file.

I need to make an installer (Which means getting the code from a git repository, configuring, executing warbler, configure warbler and copy the output to Tomcat.

Can you help me with that? What is the correct approach for this requirement? A batch file and  a EXE that executes it?

Comment: you might want to check out 'Deploying with jRuby' book - http://pragprog.com/book/jkdepj/deploying-with-jruby

Comment: in the book they create a rake task to do the deploy steps, probably more portable than a bat file, if you end up wanting to run on linux - found this link might be what you are after? http://techylinguist.com/posts/2012/01/13/deploy-jruby-rails-application-war/

Answer (score 2):

Simple question: You really have to use Tomcat under Windows?

This question because with Torquebox you could solve your problem in a super simple way. All rake tasks for deploying are there, you could deploy as a war or exploded folder. Otherwise you could use [Stompbox](https://github.com/torquebox/stompbox) to deploy the Heroku style with git.

Look at the documentation for more details: http://torquebox.org/documentation/current/deployment.html